# Set default value of react-select component from URL parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-select

The main purpose of the app is to allow users to query an RNA database via an API.
There are two parameters that can be selected: (1) the species and (2) a genomic coordinate.

I am using `react-router` and `react-select`.

After the user has chosen a species from a `<Select />` component, provided a genomic coordinate in a text field, and has clicked the submit button, the query parameters of the URL are to be updated as according to the users input. This is important so that the user can share their search query using the URL.

For example `/search?species=homo_sapiens&coords=chr1%3A100-300`.

However, I am having issues with setting the selected option of the `<Select />` component when the app first loads. That is, given the example URL, I would expect that the option for "Homo sapiens" in the *species selector* is selected and the coordinates "chr1:100-300" is autofilled in the coordinates text field.

I have provided my code in a *codesandbox.io* environment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-microservice-8j4qxg?file=/src/App.js

If any additional detail is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In the `SpeciesSelector` component when the species options are "fetched" use the same `useEffect` hook to compare the current `"species"` queryString parameter to search the data for the matching value to be used as the initial selected state. This will require switching from the `defaultValue` prop to the `value` prop as the options won't be available on the initial render when the `SpeciesSelector` component mounts.

Example:

```
export function SpeciesSelector({ handlerSpeciesChange }) {
  const [availableSpecies, setAvailableSpecies] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const [selectedSpecies, setSelectedSpecies] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/species')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // set options
        setAvailableSpecies(data);

        // set initial selected option from params
        const species = searchParams.get("species");
        setSelectedSpecies(data.find(el => el.key === species));
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleSpeciesChange = (species) => {
    handlerSpeciesChange(species);
    setSelectedSpecies(species);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={availableSpecies}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      onChange={handleSpeciesChange}
      value={selectedSpecies} // <-- use value prop for controlled inputs
      getOptionValue={(x) => x.key}
      getOptionLabel={(x) => x.label}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit set-default-value-of-react-select-component-from-url-parameter]